# Database design for getting unread article in mysql (over 100M row table)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mariadb

This information is very condensed.

There are 2 tables.

article

```
-----------------------------------
|id | weight | text               |
-----------------------------------
|1  | 10     | blah               |
|2  | 100    | blah               |
|3  | 50     | blah               |
|4  | 1000   | blah               |
-----------------------------------
```

read

```
-----------------------------------
| user_id | article_id            |
-----------------------------------
| 1       | 4                     |
| 1       | 2                     |
| 1       | 3                     |
| 2       | 3                     |
| 2       | 4                     |
-----------------------------------
```

I want to get unread articles using below query (very condensed)

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    article a LEFT OUTER JOIN read r ON r.article_id = a.id and r.user_id = 1
WHERE 
    r.id IS NULL
ORDER BY
    a.weight DESC
LIMIT 10
```

> **important information**
>
> 1. the number of `read table` rows keeps under 1000 per user. (remove old data)
> 2. weight column in article table is changed frequently. (It means order not fixed)

**problem is .. (when number of users : over 1M)**

1. the way to get unread articles using read table (not in, outer join is not important)

   - **number of `read table` rows will be over 1G**

It works well so far (current # of read table rows : 100M). but I have to prepare next step because number of users is increasing rapidly.

What is the best way for large service in this case?

(sharding? partitioning table? or redesign architecture?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `not exists` or a left join instead of `not in`.

Comment: Thanks but it's not main issue in this problem. I tried already and I found there is no big difference in performance because query plan is optimized by database.

Comment: I think it will be just fine like that, supposing you have the right indexes and data types

Comment: what are the indexes you have on that table?

Comment: @kimwz.kr where is id column in read table (r.id is null). You refer to it in your sample query? Also, your query uses r.user_id = 1. Is it always 1?

Answer (score 1):

- Add a column to `article`.  It will be a flag saying whether the article is read/unread.  (Do not make it a user count or a timestamp; that will slowdown the subsequent steps.)
- Whenever a user reads an article, check the flag and change it if needed.
- Have `INDEX(flag, weight, id) -- this will let your query run almost instantly.  This should be OK on that million-row table.

A problem:  Since you are purging (after 1000), some "read" articles can become "unread".  To deal with this, batch the purging, and gather the distinct list of articles that got purged.  Then do the tedious task of re-computing the flag, but just for those articles.  `INDEX(article_id)` will help; use `EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM read WHERE article_id = $aid )`.  (This can probably be turned into a batch operation rather than one aid at a time.)

Another problem:  secondary keys on billion-row tables are costly -- they may lead to a lot of I/O.  Before attempting to address this problem, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, plus any other common `SELECTs`.  Picking the right index(es) and datatypes is *very* important to performance in billion-row tables..

Answer (score 0):

Point is, to use the index as far as possible.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM  a
LEFT JOIN read r 
  ON r.article_id = a.id and r.user_id =1 
WHERE r.id IS NULL 
ORDER BY a.weight DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Edit:
The concern for you is the data size of `read` table and we have to reduce the data size. For that we have multiple options:

- MySQL partitions: create partitions on range of user_id ( may be 100K users per  partition
- Create multiple tables: Similar to partitioning, but you will have the data in different databases(even in different DB servers). Based on the user_id, you will decide on the table/database to join.

Also, you can think of having archival of old data periodically and the application should be smart enough to decide on whether it needs to query archived tables or live table.

Comment: Thanks I changed query in my question  but it's not main issue in this problem.

Comment: In what way will partitioning (or multiple tables) help?

Comment: The reason for slowness in the large .ibd(data) files. By making partitions or multiple tables, you are creating smaller (indexes) files. So if I query for user_id=1, i need not search in a partition which has only user_ids > 100000

Comment: If you have an index starting with `user_id` it is equally fast.

Comment: Partition will reduce index length and will create smaller ibd files. Partitions can b considered as smaller table internally. Once you cross 100m records, you will see some slowness even for indexed queries. Also I have read somewhere, tables with 300m records are not advisable